# Hashtable help- using strings

Tags: java, string, hashtable

I want to take a String str and an int wSize and use it to create a hashtable. An example is the best way to explain what I want.

For example:
str = "alphabet"
wSize = 2

I want a hashtable that looks like this:
al 0
lp 1
ph 2
ha 3
ab 4
be 5
et 6

This is what I have so far

```
public static void hashTableCreator (String str, int wSize) {
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    str = "alphabet";
    wSize = 2;
    String str2;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int value = 0;
      ht.put(str.substring(i, i + 1), value);
      value++;
    }

    Set set = ht.keySet(); 

    Iterator itr = set.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
      str2 = (String) itr.next();
      System.out.println(str2 + ": " +
                         ht.get(str2));
    }

  }
```

Comment: I don't understand, you have parameters in your method, but you're setting values to them on the next line. Whats the point of the parameters?

Comment: The question is how would i go about implementing the thing I want. And the parameters are for later use, this is just an example I want to test.

Comment: You implemented it already, as you show in your question. So what's the real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in string.substring(a,b) first argument is zero indexed and 2nd argument is 1 indexed. 
for example:

```
      "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
```

if you wanna get al from the string "alphabet" you'd have to do

```
         LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> ht = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
 int value=0;
     for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++) {
         ht.put(str.substring(i, i+2), value);
         value++;
     }
     Set<String> set = ht.keySet();
     Iterator<String> itr = set.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()) {
         String d = itr.next();
         System.out.println(d+ " "+ ht.get(d));
     }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**   al 0
lp 1
ph 2
ha 3
ab 4
be 5
et 6

Comment: I get String index out of bounds because when it gets to end I have an issue

Comment: In for: - (i < str.length() - 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
  ht.put(str.substring(i, i + 2), value);
  value++;
}
```

Comment: why are you initilizing value to 0 on every iteration ?

Comment: Thanks, I ran the code and got this ha: 3
lp: 1
be: 5
ab: 4
et: 6
al: 0
ph: 2

Comment: I want it be on order is that possible? You guys are awesome btw

Comment: Use LinkedHashMap if you want it to be ordered on insertion.

Comment: How would that work? Can you refer me to some reading material. THanks